# How can i load DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I'm Having Ms Access table Actionpoint with four rows. and i am trying to load that in the grid view using the following code

```
Dim dt as DataTable
Dim da as New OleDbDataAdapter
con.Open()
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ActionPoint",con)
da.fill(dt)
GridView1.datasource = dt.DefaultView
```

But it loads only a empty row. What is the wrong in this code?
How can i resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
GridView1 = dt.DefaultView
```

to

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
Dim dt as new DataTable
Dim da as New OleDbDataAdapter
con.Open()
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ActionPoint",con)
da.fill(dt)

GridView1.datasource = dt
```

Comment: Thanks to all,
I find the solution. the space between the * & from is the mistake that i made. Its only lead the wrong result.

`Dim dt as new DataTable`
`Dim da as New OleDbDataAdapter`
`con.Open()`
`da.datasource = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT *FROM ActionPoint",con)`
`da.fill(dt)`